# Capturing Python Sys.Exit Code with CreateProcessW

Tags: python, c++, visual-c++

I've wrote a C++ GUI that generates python scripts and calls python.exe via CreateProcessW.  However I'm having trouble reading the sys.exit code from my python script, in C++.

In Python I have:

```
import sys
...code snippets...
sys.exit(1)
```

In C++ I have:

```
if (CreateProcessW(const_cast<LPCWSTR>(FullPathToExe.c_str()),
        pwszParam, 0, 0, false,
        CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, 0, 0,
        &siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo) != false)
    {
        /* Watch the process. */
        dwExitCode = WaitForSingleObject(piProcessInfo.hProcess, (SecondsToWait * 1000));
    }
```

However it appears dwExitCode (DWORD) doesn't have what I'm looking for.  It's the same value regardless if the script has errors and Python chokes, or if it successfully runs all the way to sys.exit(1). Is there some other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's the same value regardless if the script has errors and Python chokes, or if it successfully runs all the way to sys.exit(1).

Well, yeah. 1 is the exit code returned when Python exits on an unhandled exception. 1 means there was an error.

If you want to indicate success, the exit code for that is 0. This is the default exit code if you let Python execute your script to completion, or if you do `sys.exit()` with no argument. You can also do `sys.exit(0)` explicitly if you want.

---

Aside from that, `WaitForSingleObject` doesn't return an exit code. It looks like the function to get exit codes is [`GetExitCodeProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess).

Answer (score 0):

The return value of [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) only indicates if the object being waited for actually changed state.  It's one of the values `WAIT_ABANDONED`, `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, `WAIT_TIMEOUT`, or `WAIT_FAILED`.

If you want to get a process's exit code, you need to call [`GetExitCodeProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess):

```
if (CreateProcessW(const_cast<LPCWSTR>(FullPathToExe.c_str()),
        pwszParam, 0, 0, false,
        CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, 0, 0,
        &siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo))
{
    /* Watch the process. */
    if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == WaitForSingleObject(piProcessInfo.hProcess, (SecondsToWait * 1000)))
    {
        if (!GetExitCodeProcess(piProcessInfo.hProcess, &dwExitCode))
        {
            // Handle error
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle error
    }
}
```